# Why does CPU spike when using Asp.Net Universal Session Provider?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session-state

Recently we began testing using the universal providers for sessions for Asp.Net described by Scott Hanselman here:

[Hanselman Post](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx)

Microsoft.AspNet.Providers

We're storing them in Sql Server, we use MVC 5 and our web.config looks simlar to this:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MySiteSessions" connectionString="Data Source=oursqlserver.mycompany.com;Initial Catalog=mysite_sessions;UID=sessionsuser;PWD=thepassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

```
<sessionState timeout="40" mode="Custom" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" >

<add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="MySiteSessions"  />
```

All is good for about an hour...then w3wp.exe starts to climb until it eventually chokes the box. We're using Microsoft.AspNet.Providers 2.0.0 and our site deploy targets framework 4.7.2

The site is pretty active...I was wondering if there are some performance switches that I need to be aware of.